# How do I remove Arduino completely?

Tags: apt, uninstall, purge, arduino, removing

I have tried remove Arduino on Ubuntu 16.04 but apt doesn't remove it.

These are the commands that I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove arduino
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove arduino
sudo apt-get purge arduino
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove arduino
```

After all these, Arduino still exists. What do I have to do to remove it completely?

Comment: How did you install Arduino IDE ? Via `apt-get` or by downloading from Arduino's website ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy From Arduino website

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you downloaded and installed it without using `apt` you cannot remove it using `apt`, but instead need to use the `uninstall.sh` script that was provided with the Arduino download.

Answer (score 3):

`apt` can only remove packages that you've installed via `apt` itself.  Since you've downloaded the IDE from the Arduino website, you will have to remove Arduino IDE manually. So whatever folder it is in, just delete the folder directly.